# Bedroom door has started sticking

Tags: doors

I am a new to me house (built in the 70's) and lately one of the bedroom doors, a wooden door, has started sticking in the upper corner furthest away from the hinge.  The bolts going through the hinge are all the way in and we have had some rain lately so the humidity is up which I assume could cause expansion but I would like to prevent this from happening.  We live in an area with solid foundations so foundation shift is not a likely issue.

Are their any options other than reposition the hinges or use a plane to shave off some of the top of the door?

Comment: Does the door move further open or closed when you open it partially and let go of the door?

Comment: No but the bedroom next to it has that problem (the door doesn't stick though)

Answer (score 1):

A trick I've used in the past is to take a candle and rub the wax on the door and frame where they stick. Make sure to apply a thin enough coat where the color of the wax doesn't show up on the door or frame, if that's an issue. To prevent that, use a candle that's as close of a match to the door and frame as possible .

Depending on how often the door is opened, you may have to reapply the wax every month or so.

Comment: Interesting idea, I will have to give it a shot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can sand either the door or the frame down in that area and then touch up with paint.